# Disable PDF download and print in ZK Framework

Tags: pdf, printing, download, zk, zul

I do not know how to disable PDF download and print in ZUML(ZK User Interface Markup Language). Do I need to embed a customized PDF viewer as I can only open PDF file by using Iframe tag in ZK and it uses browser pdf viewer.Therefore, it makes the task of disabling print and download pdf even harder.

Answer (score 0):

There are two other solution:

- Convert the file to HTML, image, or any other format that can be directly viewed in the browser. This conversion can be on-the-fly using a server-side (written in Java in this case), or you can just pre-convert all files to a readable one.
- The other approach, which is the best, is to use a **Flash-based PDF viewer** (such as http://flexpaper.devaldi.com/). This is easy, flexible and doesn't require writing server-side code. This approach is used by many Document-sharing sites (e.g. http://www.scribd.com/, http://www.slideshare.net/, http://www.docstoc.com/)

(For reference only, If you don't want disable download pdf file, there are few solutions:
http://zkfiddle.org/sample/1dnhepc/11-PDF-viewer 
http://zkfiddle.org/sample/3ojd4og/1-PDF-Viewer-in-ZK-using-Iframe#source-2 )

Answer (score 0):

After [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32571725/pass-value-from-viewmodel-to-script-in-zk) question I discovered the existence of PDFObject, a simple javascript plugin to embed PDF documents inside a page. I've made a [fiddle](http://zkfiddle.org/sample/hlaak0/1-PDFObject-ZK) so you can see it in action.

**index.zul**

```
<?script type="text/javascript" src="http://pdfobject.com/scripts/pdfobject.js"?>
<zk>
  <script type='text/javascript'>
  function embedPDF(_url){
    var myPDF = new PDFObject({ 
      url: _url
    }).embed('pdfContainer');  
  }
</script>

  <vlayout apply="org.zkoss.bind.BindComposer" viewModel="@id('vm') @init('pkg$.TestVM')" xmlns:w="http://www.zkoss.org/2005/zk/client">
    <listbox model="@load(vm.pdfUrls)">
      <template name="model" var="url">
        <listitem>
          <listcell label="@load(url)" />
          <listcell>
            <button label="load" onClick="@command('loadPdf', url=url)" />
          </listcell>
        </listitem>
      </template>
    </listbox>
    <vlayout xmlns:n="native">
      <n:object id="pdfContainer"></n:object>
    </vlayout>
  </vlayout>
</zk>
```

**TestVM.java**

```
import org.zkoss.bind.annotation.AfterCompose;
import org.zkoss.bind.annotation.Command;
import org.zkoss.bind.annotation.BindingParam;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.zkoss.zk.ui.util.Clients;

public class TestVM {

    List<String> pdfUrls;

    @AfterCompose
    public void afterCompose() {
      pdfUrls = new ArrayList<String>();
      pdfUrls.add("http://www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf");
      pdfUrls.add("https://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/xml/AdobeXMLFormsSamples.pdf");
      pdfUrls.add("https://www.iscp.ie/sites/default/files/pdf-sample.pdf");
    }

  @Command
    public void loadPdf(@BindingParam("url")String url) {
      Clients.evalJavaScript("embedPDF('"+ url +"')");
    }

  public List<String> getPdfUrls() {
    return pdfUrls;
  }

}
```

Cheers, Alex